# Highlight rows with pval lower than 0.05 in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to highlight rows with pvalue lower than 0.05
The code belows is how i render my table.

My table is a classical anova table. The pvalue is the column "Pr(>F)"

```
output$tablepermanova <- DT::renderDataTable(
       values$anovatable, options = list(orderClasses = TRUE),
       caption="Analysis of variance",
       filter = 'top'   )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `formatStyle` in combination with `styleInterval`, see for some examples [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html).

We do not have your data, but a working example is given below with the `mtcars` dataset, where we highlight all rows for cars with less than (or equal to) 5 cylinders. Replacing `'cyl'` with the column name that contains your p-values, and `5` with `0.05` should do the trick.

Hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('table')
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(mtcars) %>% formatStyle(
        'cyl',
        target = 'row',
        backgroundColor = styleInterval(5, c('orange','white'))
      )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```